# Unable to connect to: ws://hostname:5240/MAAS/ws

Tags: server, maas, openstack

My MAAS server has been running for several months, building OpenStack cloud configurations and tearing them down, but then it starts giving the error message

```
Unable to connect to: ws://hostname:5240/MAAS/ws
```

when going to to the node list.

I have tried rebooting the server, reconfiguring `maas-region-controller`, everything I can think of.  I can `telnet` to the port and something is definitely listening on it.

How do I recover from this?  My only successful method in the past has been to wipe the disk and do a total reinstall and reconfigure, starting over.  This happens regularly.

Comment: I tried uninstalling maas maas-cli maas-cluster-controller maas-common maas-region-controller maas-region-controller-min without deleting the database and reinstalling.  No luck.  Then uninstalled .... with deleting the database.  Reinstall is failing.  The dumped database is 1.5GB.  I guess it is time to wipe the disk and do a clean install.  How does one keep an openstack cloud running if the MAAS server keeps doing this and needs to be reinstalled from iso?

Comment: Did a clean install of 14.04.3 and installed MAAS 1.8.0+bzr4001-0ubuntu2~trusty1 and it does the same thing right out of the box without configuring anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make certain that port 5240 was available between my desktop and the maas server.  It was not open which caused the failure.  After making port 5240 available it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
You can access it directly from http://hostname:5240
I successfully accessed it directly even though http://hostname/MAAS/ giving those errors.